# Showing the leapfrog scheme is consistent for $u_t+au_x=0$.

Tags: numerical-methods

To show that a scheme is consistent we define a smooth function $\phi$, and consider the following:

$$\frac{\phi_m^{n+1}-\phi_m^{n-1}}{2k}+a\left(\frac{\phi_{m+1}^{n}-\phi_{m-1}^{n}}{2h}\right)=0$$

I'm stuck on showing how to demonstrate this.  I understand that we use Taylor series, then we find the difference between $\phi u-\phi_{k,h}=0$ as $(h,k)\to 0$.

Comment: Just expand each grid function using taylor expansion. Looks like it's (2,2) accurate so you don't need many terms in each expansion.